# Do I need external storage for my front-end application?

Tags: webpack, caching, storage

I have a webpack application that I am attempting to upgrade. I am upgrading webpack to version 5 and babel to version 7 (I know, *tons* of fun). *Anyway...*

Everything looked great until it went live in Production and we were getting customer complaints. Apparently the app was broken...yeah, it was. We reverted the code, re-deployed and all was saved.

Turns out that customers' browsers were caching `app.js` which was the name of the same file in the new code. Customers browsers were trying to build the new bundle using the `app.js` file from the previous release. The advice? Try it again in Incognito and it worked.

My solution is to implement cache-busting at the webpack level. It works because I deployed the app locally and tried it in the same browser instance I had opened previously. On load it worked since the `app.js` file now had a hash like `app.453095jfmn45.js`.

Question though. For customers who cached the old `app.js`, cache-busting still would not help here, right? Their browser would attempt to retrieve `app.js` and it simply would not exist because only the hashed one does. Does this mean I have to keep multiple versions of my app around in some external persistent storage? In this way, "old" customers requesting `app.js` would not be affected and new customers would get the hashed version. Is this the way?